# Highcharts - Column Chart Drilldown, how to change the drilldown bar color based on some value

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, column-chart

I'm trying to make drilldown for a column chart in highcharts using below js

```
// Create the chart
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Browser market shares. January, 2015 to May, 2015'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Click the columns to view versions. Source: <a href="http://netmarketshare.com">netmarketshare.com</a>.'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Total percent market share'
        }

    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.y:.1f}%'
            }
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.2f}%</b> of total<br/>'
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Brands',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [{
            name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
            y: 56.33,
            drilldown: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer'
        }, {
            name: 'Firefox',
            y: 10.38,
            drilldown: 'Firefox'
        }]
    }],
    drilldown: {
        series: [{
            name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
            id: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
            data: [
                [
                    'v11.0',
                    24.13
                ],
                [
                    'v8.0',
                    17.2
                ],
                [
                    'v6.0',
                    1.06
                ],
                [
                    'v7.0',
                    0.5
                ]
            ]
        }, {
            name: 'Firefox',
            id: 'Firefox',
            data: [
                [
                    'v35',
                    2.76
                ],
                [
                    'v34',
                    1.27
                ],
                [
                    'v38',
                    1.02
                ],
                [
                    'v33',
                    0.22
                ],
                [
                    'v32',
                    0.15
                ]
            ]
        }]
    }
});
```

Is it possible to change only the drilldown column colors based on some different not the x-axis or y-axis value.

Here in below data based on "new_info" i want to change colour according

```
  [{"name":Microsoft Internet Explorer, data :[['v11.0',14, (new_info) 6] , ['v8.0',10, 8(new_info)] , ['v6.0',8, 3 (new_info)]]
```

If value is between 10 - 8 red, 7-5 amber, 4-3 yellow.

When I click on drilldown it should show me some n column chart few columns in red few in yellow few in orange and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [zones](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.zoneAxis) like that :

```
...
zones: [{
            value: 4,
            color: '#ffcc00'
        }, {
            value: 7.1,
            color: '#AA7F39'
        }, {
                value:13,
            color: '#ff0000'
        }]
...
```

Here a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/core972/6pnL4s1x/)

Comment: is it possible to add a new field and its  value not the one in data array.  I don't want to touch the data array but there is another value associated with data array elements depending on that i want to change the value and color

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to achieve. Please explain that on some example.

Comment: @KamilKulig  the above solution, values used in zones is is the drill down y-axis is value but what if i want to differentiate it based on totally different value not same as x or y axis.

Comment: Then you need to do it manually. Iterate all the data and apply appropriate color to every point.

Comment: @KamilKulig i need to change the JS completely ?

Comment: Take a look at this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vm4fx3kf/ I created a separate property named `param` and I use it to determine which color should be applied for every point.