# Column based Highchart drilldown series assign color code to each column

Tags: javascript, highcharts, colors, column-chart

I Want to assign my own color for each column for drilldown graph of column based chart. So i have created zones and assigned color codes based on some pre calculation.

My code is as below :

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Browser market shares. January, 2015 to May, 2015'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Click the columns to view versions. Source: <a href="http://netmarketshare.com">netmarketshare.com</a>.'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Total percent market share'
        }

    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.y:.1f}%'
            }
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.2f}%</b> of total<br/>'
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Brands',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [{
            name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
            y: 56.33,
            drilldown: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer'
        }, {
            name: 'Firefox',
            y: 10.38,
            drilldown: 'Firefox'
        }]
    }],
    drilldown: {
        series: [{
            name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
            id: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
            data: [
                [
                    'v11.0',
                    14 // Over max set in zone get default color
                ],
                [
                    'v8.0',
                    10
                ],
                [
                    'v6.0',
                    8
                ],
                [
                    'v7.0',
                    4
                ]
            ],
            zones: [{
                color: '#ffcc00'
            }, {
                color: '#AA7F39'
            }, {
                color: '#ff8000'
            }, {
                color: '#FFFF00'
            }]
        }, {
            name: 'Firefox',
            id: 'Firefox',
            data: [
                [
                   'v35',
                    12,

                ],
                [
                    'v34',
                    10
                ],
                [
                    'v38',
                    7
                ],
                [
                    'v33',
                    4
                ],
                [
                    'v32',
                    3
                ]
            ],
            zones: [{
                color: '#FFFF00'
            }, {
                color: '#FFFF00'
            }, {
                color: '#ff8000'
            }, {
                color: '#AA7F39'
            }]
        }]
    }
});
```

My Fiddle is

https://jsfiddle.net/jqefrrj0/

Now when I click on Microsoft, the drilldown graph has  all yellow color columns, whereas I want it to change as per the each color given in zones.

Like first yellow, then mustard, orange,  yellow.

How can I achieve the above colors for each column of drilldown series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to set the `zones.value` [Documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.zones)

```
        zones: [{
            color: '#ffcc00',
            value:5
        }, {
            color: '#AA7F39',
            value:12
        }, {
            color: '#ff8000'
        }, {
            color: '#FFFF00'
        }]
```

[Updadted Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jqefrrj0/4/)

Comment: yeah can i do without setting  value ?? thing is few with same value can have different colors depending on some other paramaters

Comment: Please see my last comment under the answer from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48660900/highcharts-column-chart-drilldown-how-to-change-the-drilldown-bar-color-based/48661291?noredirect=1#comment84770779_48661291

Comment: @KamilKulig  you are assigning the color based on param from data set.   What if i already have a predined color for each drilldown column and i just want to assign it to the respective column

Comment: Why don't you do it in the point's options? Example (drilldown to Microsoft Internet Explorer): https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/y8jntmfw/

Comment: @KamilKulig This is exactly what I was looking for. I tried but with [ ] and it gave me error.  Thank you so much  !!!!